# NuGet package reference & version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I tried crawling through the documentation for NuGet and Visual Studio but did not find an exact answer for my question. Also am new to using NuGet.

If I have a packages.config like below:

```
<packages>
  <package id="xxx.SomePackage" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

And a similar reference in my .csproj for the project:

```
<Reference Include="xxx.SomePackage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\xxx.SomePackage.1.0.1\lib\net45\xxx.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Suppose I have a newer version which I want the projects to use namely 1.0.2, should I manually change each csproj/packages.config reference to point to that version or is NuGet smart enough to get and apply only the latest version to my projects ? I have a lot of projects so it's a pain to change for each one.

Note: I read about using SpecificVersion: False. Is that something I can use ?
Note: I also read about "Update-Package -reinstall". Is this the best and preferred method for scenarios like mine ?

Comment: You would have to manually upgrade the packages to their latest. VS does have NuGet Package Manager to help you upgrade all packages of a solution.

Comment: @Adi, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved your issue? If not, Please let me know the latest information about this issue.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Thanks for your info it is certainly helpful and I made a note of it. Will be trying the console update soon and I will reply to your answer on how it went ^^

Comment: @Adi, what about this issue now?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT We ended up using another way of doing this but I had a follow up question, supposing I deploy this code (with NuGet references) to multiple boxes, would I need to "Enable Package Restore" in order for the DLLs to be downloaded from NuGet on the new boxes ?

Answer (score 2):

> should I manually change each csproj/packages.config reference to point to that version or is NuGet smart enough to get and apply only the latest version to my projects ? I have a lot of projects so it's a pain to change for each one.'

No, you don not need to manually change each csproj/packages.config reference to point to that version. NuGet smart enough to get and apply only the latest version to your projects.

You can use the command line `Update-Package -Id <package_name> -Version 1.0.2` in the Package Manager Console, without specifying any particular project, `Update-Package` affects all projects in a solution. See [update-package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-update-package) for more detail info.

Alternatively, you can also update all projects via Manager NuGet Packages for Solution. Right click your solution (not project), select Manager NuGet Packages for Solution, switch to Updates tab, choose the package you need to upgrade, then select the projects you want to update the package:

[image]

Besides, `Update-Package -reinstall` is used to reinstall packages, using  this command is much easier than removing a package and then trying to locate the same package in the NuGet gallery with the **same version**. So this command would not update the version of the package.

Hope this helps.